# get query string in array with bash

Tags: bash, sqlite

I have a sqlite with a table with 2 columns. I would like to get the two values of the columns in every variable or in an array. For instance:

```
table A
COLUMN A         COLUMN B
credit and risk  David
nothing          susan
.....
```

and I would like to obtain: Variable A="credit and risk" and variable B="David" then Variable A ="nothing" and variable B= "susan" and so on.
I'm trying with these code but if the column A have space I can't get the string complete, for example I obtain "credit" only. My code:

```
valores=($(sqlite3 alcampo.db "select DESCRIPTION, URL  FROM SUBCATEGORYS"))

cnt=${#valores[@]}
echo "cuenta es ... $cnt"
for (( i=0 ; i<cnt ; i++ ))
do
    echo "Record No. $i: ${valores[$i]}"
    fieldA=${valores[0]}
echo "campo a es ... $fieldA"
    fieldB=${valores[1]}
echo "campo B es ... $fieldB"

done
```

Could you help me please? Thanks

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for help on how to read lines from streams. Then you just need to pick a delimiter that *isn't* in your data to split on.

Answer (score 1):

There might be better ways to get this done.
It sounds like you don't want to keep the variables after you echo them.

```
while read line; do

  fieldA=$( echo "$line" | sed -n "s/\(.*\)\s\{2,\}.*/\1/p" )
  fieldB=$( echo "$line" | sed -n "s/.*\s\{2,\}\(.*\)/\1/p" )

  echo "campo A es ... ${fieldA}"
  echo "campo B es ... ${fieldB}"

done < <(sqlite3 alcampo.db "select DESCRIPTION, URL FROM SUBCATEGORYS")
```

This will ready your command "sqlite3 ..." directly into the while loop.  The while loop will assign each line to the variable "$line".

We then echo the $line variable and sed it to grab the information we want.  The sed is based on having 2 or more spaces between the columns...it was the only way I could think to delimit the data based off of what you posted.

- $( ) -- command substitution
- -n -- don't print
- s -- substitute
- \( -- begin capture group 1
- .* -- match anything
- \) -- end capture group 1
- \s{2,} -- 2 or more white-space characters
- .* -- anything else
- \1 -- output capture group 1
- p -- print it

I hope this helps.  Let me know.